# VIM for Windows: How to edit to the end of line but before EOL character

Tags: windows, vim

**What I am trying to do:**
For example, I have a line in my code that looks like this

```
something.something()
```

I would like to add `print()` around it:

```
print(something.something())
```

**How I am doing it:**
I type in vim: `^c$print()<Esc>P` meaning:

1. put cursor to the beginning of the line,
2. change entire line,
3. type in `print()`,
4. paste entire line back before `print`'s `)`.

**The Problem:**
Unfortunately the `c$` part cut the EOL character as well. so the subsequent `P` operation will just paste the line on top of `print()`. So the end result will look like this:

```
something.something()
print()
```

**My Thoughts:**
Right now the work around is using `v` mode to highlight entire line except for the EOL character first, then do the above.

I am looking for something akin to `ct$` `ci$`, but none of them works. my line doesn't always end with `()`, it could be `__dict__` or just plain text, so `cf)` is handy but I am looking for something more universal. Thanks.

Comment: I would like to welcome any working arounds. Doesn't have to be based on `change to end`

Comment: Is vim-surround of any help? https://github.com/tpope/vim-surround

Comment: So it is as I was afraid, It is not doable in VIM except for plug-ins.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem. No `\r` is entered for me. Is your fileformat `dos`?

Comment: @L3viathan vim for windows, I was editing a python file.

Comment: I see. I would add that detail to your question then, as this doesn't happen on \*n\*x.

Comment: @L3viathan thank you, done

Comment: @eliu the mere fact that someone suggested a plugin certainly doesn't mean that it is not doable in vim without a plugin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's doable out of the box.

Assuming your description of what you are doing is exact, the reason what you are doing doesn't work **is most likely caused by something in your config** because `c$` (or its better alternative `C`) should never yank the EOL.

Here is a demonstration using your method as described in your question:

```
^c$print()<Esc>P
```

and the method I would use:

```
^Cprint(<C-r>")<Esc>
```

[image: works]

Comment: @ romainl this is very embarrassing indeed, I uninstalled gvim, deleted _vimrc and reinstalled it again, I don't have this problem anymore. So what settings are we talking about here? Thank you for the editing, very professional.

Comment: Something in the `_vimrc` you deleted, probably.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you want to be going into edit mode at all.  Just do:

```
:s/something.something()/print(&)/g
```

Note that you can do this pretty easily interactively (eg, you don't have to type 'something.something()') by yanking something.something into the unnamed register (eg, put your cursor on the text and hit 'yiw', but what gets yanked exactly will depend on the current setting of `iskeyword`), and typing `:s/<ctrl>r"/...`

Or, as Christian Gibbons points out in the comments, if you want to replace the entire line you can simply do:

```
:s/.*/print(&)
```

Comment: I'm not sure this should be a global regex.  Also, it might be a bit of a handful.  OP mentions performing the surround from the start of line to end of line, so a maybe a regex that matches against the entire current line and surrounds.

Comment: Perhaps something like `:s/^.\+$/print(&)/`

Answer (score 1):

Try `^cg_print()<Esc>P`.

The `g_` movement means "to the last non-blank character of the line", and since in Windows it appears the carriage return is part of the line if you yank/delete, using `_g` instead of `$` on Windows may be advisable.

If you find yourself almost never needing `$`, you can swap the two commands in your `.vimrc`:

```
onoremap g_ $
onoremap $ g_
```